# Angular material table not showing data properly on the webpage

Tags: angular, api

I have no error in my console, but not able to display it in Material Data Table. Looking in the code for a while but can't figure it out.
Here is the code of users.component.ts

````
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { UserDataList } from '../models/api-models/users.model';
import { UserData } from '../models/ui-models/users.model';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})

@Injectable()
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit{
  userslist: UserDataList[] = [];
  displayedColumns:string[] =[
  'id',
  'orgName',
  'address',
  'state',
  'country',
  'city',
  'zipCode',
  'emailId',
  'website',
  'primaryContact',
  'primaryContactMobile',
  'secondaryContact',
  'secondaryContactMobile',
  'programs',
  'status'];
  
  dataSource= new MatTableDataSource<UserDataList>(this.userslist);

  constructor(private userService:UserService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //Fetch Users
   this.getUsersList();
  }


  getUsersList(): any{
    this.userService.getAllUsers()
    .subscribe(
      (successResponse)=>{
        console.log(successResponse.data[0].Id);
        // console.log(successResponse[1].State);
        this.userslist = successResponse.data;
        this.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource(this.userslist);
      },
    (errorResponse)=>{
      console.log(errorResponse);
    }

    )

  }
}```


And the html code is:

<div class="container">
    <div>
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
          
            <!-- Id Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- OrgName Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="orgName">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> OrgName </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.orgName}} </td>
              </ng-container>

              <!-- Address Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="address">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Address </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.address}} </td>
              </ng-container>

              <!-- State Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="state">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> State </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.state}} </td>
              </ng-container>

              <!-- country Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="country">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Country </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.country}} </td>
              </ng-container>

              <!-- Position Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="city">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> City </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.city}} </td>
              </ng-container>

              <!-- zipCode Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="zipCode">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ZipCode </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.zipCode}} </td>
              </ng-container>
             <!-- emailId Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="emailId">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> EmailId </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.emailId}} </td>
              </ng-container>

            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
          </table>
          
          
    </div>
</div>
````

This code only displays the "zipcode" column and the rest of the columns shows empty. What is wrong with this code? Can anyone help with this?[You can check it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrdDI.png)

Comment: are you getting an error on the console? maybe that some of the element.* are undefined?

Comment: No not getting any error in the console.

Comment: Every element is defined.

Comment: console.log(successResponse.data[0].Id); is this log working?
seems that you are having an issue with the first letter in uppercase on the data array. check for it.